# Was the diagetic music in The Expanse specifically written for the show?

Tags: the-expanse-2015

I'm referring to the [music that the characters are listening to within the show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diegetic_music), not the music that accompanies the scenes.

To me, this music sounds more futuristic or something that has been written to fit within the setting of the show.

Some examples:

> S3:E7 – Where Manéo is seen slingshotting around the planets and
> finally into the ring.
>
> S5:E2/3 – Where Drummers crew are celebrating around the table.

Comment: https://www.tunefind.com/show/the-expanse/season-3/63810#songs

Comment: @Valorum - thanks for the edit and I've learnt a new word :)

Comment: Not only that, but I've corrected a significant mistake because *"actual music"* is another (film school) word for *"diagetic music"*, which I only learned today.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first song you're referring to (where he slingshots around the ring) is [*Highway Star* by Deep Purple](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UAKCR7kQMTQ), written in 1972.

That being said, that particular *arrangement* was written by Cory Todd and was specifically for the show.

Comment: Now I know why it sounded familiar. (Just now binge watching expanse)